# How to recover data from a json object in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, angular2-services

I'm trying to use values obtained from an API that return the values in JSON.

I can see the values of the object in the console. But I can not use them apart.

How do I assign values in different variables, separately?

I want to validate the data before sending it to the HTML.

> IMG
>   [Values in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGdhM.png)

```
this.http
  .get(this.url + e)
  .map((res) => res.json())
  .subscribe((data) => this.user = data);
```

> OR

```
getData() {
let e = md5(this.userString);
this.http
  .get(this.url + e)
  .map((res) => res.json())
  .subscribe(
  user => this.user = user,
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>)}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can't add comments but I think it is in the html page, call the function in a certain div, then call the data with the specified information you want, for example in your case it is like that:

`<div click()= "getData()">
<p *ngFor="let i of data"> {{i.username}}
<p *ngFor="let i of data"> {{i.id}}`

if the data was array it would work.
This is how I understand your question.

Comment: Thanks, but if I try to use that same data in typescript.

what I need to do?

Comment: I want to validate the data before sending it to the HTML.

Sorry if I could not explain it very well.

Comment: I understand you, you can try this: declare a variable globally, then use it in the function `getData` by giving the value of the data to that variable but you have to compare in the same function, cause outside the function it is not defined. @OsmarFerreira

Comment: Nice, thanks @Zainab Hammami.

Sorry, but one last question, can I get the value ID of the `getData` function with the global variable? To use in another function?

Comment: No problem, Try it, but I don't believe it would work cause it is inside a function. @OsmarFerreira

Comment: In the same function I can use something like this

`<p *ngFor="let i of data"> {{i.username}}`

Comment: sure you can make `for loop` inside any function but that one: `<p *ngFor="let i of data"> {{i.username}}` is html code. @OsmarFerreira

Comment: Thank you very much.

It worked.

Sorry for my lack of experience.

Have a nice day.

Comment: you are welcome, it is okay but would you please accept my answer @OsmarFerreira

Comment: no problem, glad to hear it worked, all the best @OsmarFerreira